# How can I store the value of a Css Property (height in px) in a Javascript variable as a number?

Tags: javascript

How can I store the value of a Css Property (height in px) in a    Javascript variable as a number?
somediv.style.height (in px) should be stored in a
    variable.

```
<style>

     #somediv {
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
     }

</style>

<script>

    let somediv = document.getElementById('somediv');
    let height = somediv.style.height;

</script
```

but this doesnt work. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `window.getComputedStyle` to get CSS values after they have been computed by the browser:

```
const divElement = document.getElementById("somediv");
const style = window.getComputedStyle(divElement);
const height = style.getPropertyValue("height");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with some simple jQuery, using `.height()` . The Code is as followed:

```js
    var height = $(".somediv").height();
    console.log(height);
```

```css
     .somediv {
        width: 100px;
        height: 200px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somediv">
  <h2>Tokyo</h2>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```